# RxJava call service every x seconds with onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I need to make the same network call every X seconds so I used the code below

```
Observable.interval(X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(n -> myCall())
                .flatMap(response -> Observable.from(response.getList())
                .doOnNext(object -> createNewObject())
                .doOnCompleted(() -> myStuff())
                .subscribe()
```

But the problem is that I never get doOnCompleted called.
Is there a way to keep calling my service every X seconds but with an onComplete after every call ?

Comment: It is not possible. Why do you want something like that?

Comment: My service return me a list of object, so I want to update my data when the iteration on my object list is done.

Comment: In that case it looks like instead of  .doOnCompleted(() -> myStuff()) you should use .doOnNext(() -> myStuff())

Comment: I would like to call myStuff with my final list of object to avoid doing the same treatment multiple times

Comment: what is the final list? you're doing infinite interval. please describe what is your scenario requirements, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's say I want to build a library app. I need to update the state of my books every minute (is the book available or not). I need then to update the UI. Imagine I use some SDK to create my book list which take a list of books available and a list of book not available to update the UI. It wouldbe faster to call this method just once on the doOnCompleted than calling it every time on doOnNext

Comment: you didn't explain yet what is the 'once' ? you're doing repeat work every minute per your definition, what work you want to execute once? and when is this 'once'?

Comment: once every call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move your stream operators into the first flatMap, there you'll receive your onComplete call.

```
Observable.interval(X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(n -> myCall().flatMap(response -> Observable.from(response.getList())
                .doOnNext(object -> createNewObject())
                .doOnCompleted(() -> myStuff())
            )
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 2):

```
Observable.interval(X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(n -> myCall())
            .doOnNext(() -> myStuff())
            .subscribe()
```

And for network call use subscribeOn and observeOn, 
And implement doOnError action doOnError(() -> showNoInternetConnection())

doOnCompleted never call for interval!!!

Final code:

```
Observable.interval(X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(n -> myCall())
            .doOnNext(() -> myStuff())
            .doOnError(() -> showNoInternetConnection())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe()
```

Or you can use subscribe this prams.

```
Observable.interval(X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(n -> myCall())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::myStuff(), this::showNoInternetConnection())
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question. Is there a way to call my service every x seconds (without interval since doOnCompleted is never called) ?

Comment: Why do you need the onComplete? you want to perform something on each result of network call, so just use doOnNext (or subscribe) and perform the operation as suggested here.

Comment: If I wanted to use onNext I would not have asked that question

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. *Complete* event [by definition](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) means that the stream is closed and no more signals are to be expected.

Comment: Ok, so that is completely impossible with Rx ?